# start and stop a linux shell command from a c program without blocking current execution

Tags: c, rtl-sdr

```
while(variable > 0){
  updatevariable(); //variable gets updated from UDP serevr.
  // i want to execute a shell command here without blocking current execution. 
}
```

i tried using system() function but it is blocking current execution, i should be able to stop the shell command if the condition doesn't satisfy and shouldn't wait until the shell command finishes execution. (the shell command i'm using is rtl_fm and it doesn't stop execution until we manually stop it). i'm writing this code specifically for linux OS.
And i exactly know the time when the variable falls below 0. is there any way to execute shell command for certain period of time?

haven't tried process, threads yet.
PS: This is my first question on this platform.

Comment: you want [fork-exec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec)

Comment: Thanks. created a child process and used execvp() and i'm able to do stuff exactly as i wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a new process with fork or clone

```
int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *stack, int flags, void *arg, ...
             /* pid_t *parent_tid, void *tls, pid_t *child_tid */ );
```

(if you need more precise control over what pieces of execution context are shared between the calling process 'parent' and the child process. see [clone_man_pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) then you can send your newly created child to run some other code (without waiting or blocking your current shell). this is done with the exec system calls family [exec_family_man_pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. solved the problem by using fork and execvp().